# Get the shortest div after DOM rebuild

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with finding the shortest div (according to it's current height) after a DOM rebuild (with .append()). I want to append data from a json array one after another, but always to the current shortest div (to make them kind of even height).
This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="article_column" id="data0"></div>
<div class="article_column" id="data1"></div>
<div class="article_column" id="data2"></div>
<div class="article_column" id="data3"></div>
```

And this i what i am currently doing in jquery:

```
 $.each(data, function (i, column) {
     var shortest = [].reduce.call($(".article_column"), function (sml, cur) {
         return $(sml).height() < $(cur).height() ? sml : cur;
     });
     $(shortest).append(column.html);
 });
```

This seems to be kinda working, but only for the first 4 elements or so. After that most of the data is getting appended to only one div. Obviously this is not what i am looking for. Is there something wrong with my code? I would suspect, that the DOM is not getting updated as fast, so that the wrong div gets selected.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the reason for doing it like this? Couldn't you just specify a  CSS `min-height` or a fixed `height`?

Comment: I am dynamically loading more data and i want them to be evenly appended to the divs to keep kind of the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to any suggestions. I got it working. The problem wasn't my jQuery, but the css of the html i appended. It was set to `width: auto;` so while appending it, the div only had a width of like 5 pixel. Therefore many divs could be appended to one column before it would affect the height. Setting a `min-width` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is best way to do that but this what I would do

```
var shortest = null, height = 100000;

$.each($('.article_column'), function(k, v){
  if(parseInt($(v).height()) < height) {
      shortest = $(v);
      height = $(v).height();
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/IXeTewU/1/)

Comment: Same problem. Most of the data getting appended to only one div. I am not exactly sure what causes this problem.. I guess its because i am looping through a json array, executing this every loop through and adding the data to the shortest...Maybe jQuery just can't handle this`?